# Surjective Function - can some elements in A have image which isn't in B

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions, definition

f : A → B

For f to be a surjective function, for every $b \in B$, there needs to a $a \in A$ such that f(a) = b

However, it is also necessary, that every $a \in A$, $f(a) \in B$?

i.e. can there be elements in A which have an image which is not in B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $f : A \rightarrow B$ already means that for each $a \in A$ it is $f(a) \in B$.

Saying that a function is surjective implies that you are talking about the previously declared codomain ($B$).

Comment: So as per the definition of injective, surjective & bijective functions, every element in A should always map to an element in B, right?

Comment: @user93353 Per the definition of the function itself, every element in A gets mapped (by f) to an element of B. The definition of injectivity and surjectivity is not relevant to this single statement.

Answer (score 1):

If f is the function means every element of A has an image in B (by the definition of function only). So by the definitions of Surjective, Injective, and Bijective mappings, one can examine the nature of mapping in B (one-one or Onto).